# Haskell-a function that applies a function on a list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function that accepts a function as parameter, and applies that function on every pair of elements in a list. For example, if I call my function `foldPairs`, then I would use it as so:

```
foldPairs (+) [1..10]

[3,7,11,15,19]
```

I tried using `foldl` in my attempt...

```
foldPairs :: (a->a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
foldPairs func lis = foldl func lis
```

However this clearly does not work. I think I might have to use `curried` and `uncurried` but I am not quite sure how. Could someone help me out?

Comment: What if the list has odd number of elements?

Comment: You write "every pair", but the example is only for "adjacent elements".

Comment: if it has odd number of elements, there can be an error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that for an odd-numbered input list we just discard the last element, the following will do the required:

```
foldPairs :: (a->a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
foldPairs _ [] = []
foldPairs _ [_] = []
foldPairs f (x:y:xs) = f x y : foldPairs f xs
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I would go with is to turn `[1..10]` into `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]`, then filter out any lists of length 1, convert to tuples, then map your function:

```
chunks :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunks n = reverse . go []
    where
        go acc [] = acc
        go acc xs =
            let (h, t) = splitAt n xs
            in go (h:acc) t
```

Then simply

```
foldpairs :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
foldpairs f
    = map (uncurry f)
    . map (\[x, y] -> (x, y))
    . filter ((== 2) . length)
    . chunks 2
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well, it works. No, I didn't think of using simple pattern matching at first, which would be the canonical answer, but in even slightly more complicated situations or where something other than lists are used this would be easier to switch to some other data structure. Pattern matching doesn't work so well on `Vector`s for example, but it would be pretty easy to make `chunks` work on vectors, and then a few quick adjustments to get `foldpairs` to work too. It's not the most efficient, but I don't write industry quality code for simple SO questions, just what illustrates the point.

Comment: @EugeneSh. [As you can see](https://gist.github.com/313829ec3c5cde121d22) it's more or less trivial to make this work with `Vector`, and I'm even being pretty lazy here.  How would you do this for `Vector`?

Comment: I think you are trying to solve a different problem here. Just by looking at the OP function signature, it is different. I agree that it might solve some other problems generically, but.. take the context in account :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. The only thing I changed in the type signature was making it more general. Dismissing someone's answer without constructive feedback is not useful on SO, but at least I can point out that if one wanted to make this work with other data structures then function composition makes this easier than pattern matching does. The code I posted here is not the best, and I didn't intend for it to be, but if you're going to question it's intentions then at least have good reasons to.

Comment: Sorry, there was no intention to offend, this is exactly why I've asked, since sometimes people here might have a strange sense of humor, so I was not sure this is not the case here, since at the first glance it seem like a heavily overcomplicated answer to a simple question, but it might be not in some cases that you have pointed.